# How to create a button that will call a page as HttpGet

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm learning MVC and ASP.NET. I have a table in which the last column contains an Edit button for each row. This works fine and I like the look and feel of the button vs a link, but when it opens the page, the HttpPost action is called in the controller.  I understand why this is happening, its a submit button, and its acting like that page is being submitted.  How do I modify this so that I have a button that redirects to a HttpGet for that page?  (In Razor ...)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Purchase"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `FormMethod.Get` to the `BeginForm()` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) as you'll want to save the data that's posted.

In the post action you would Redirect to a GET action (which could be the same page with updated information).  This way, subsequent refreshes (F5) would not resubmit the POST.  It's  a nice pattern to use.